# JMeter CSV Dataset Config: how to move through variables in the same thread?

Tags: apache, csv, random, dataset, jmeter

I'm using a CSV dataset config element, which is reading from a file like this:

```
abd
sds
ase
sdd
ssd
cvv
```

Which, basically, has a number of 3 letter random string.

I'm assigning them to a variable called `${random_3}`.

Now, I want to use values from this list multiple times within the same thread, but each time I want to move to next. For example, I want the first sampler to use `abd`, the 2nd to use `sds`, then `ase`, etc. But if I just use `${random_3}` then only the first one (abd) is used wherever it's referred to. Is there a way I can specify to loop through the values from the CSV dataset within a thread?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**CSV Data Set Config** works fine for this. All of the values need to be in one column in the file and assign them to the variable as described.

Create a **Thread Group** that has as many threads for as many users as you want iterating over the file (i.e. acting on the HTTP Request). Assuming 1 user, set the number of threads to 1, loop count to 1.

Inside the thread group you will need to add a **Loop Controller** or a **While Controller**. You indicated that you want to loop through the whole data set. If you add a loop controller you will want to set the Loop Count to 6, since you have 6 values, one for each value. Alternately (and easier for processing the whole file) add a While Controller instead of a Loop Controller and set ${random_3} as the while condition.

It is important to set the CSV Data Set **Recycle on EOF** and **Stop Thread on EOF** values correctly. If you plan to iterate over the file more than once you must set "Recycle on EOF" to *True* (i.e. instruct jMeter to move back to the top of the CSV file). Set "Stop Thread on EOF" to *False* if you are using a loop controller, *true* if you are using a while controller and want to stop after reading the whole csv dataset.

Add the CSV Data Set Config as a child of the controller along with the HTTP Request. View the results using any listener you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

CSV data set moves through file only when each thread iteration starts.

You can use [Raw Data Source](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RawDataSource) PreProcessor to move throuhg file with each request, that's your solution.

Comment: Thank you I had look but it didn't seem to be directly related to my use case and a bit fiddly in general.

Comment: Actually it is solution. You may ask at project's mailing list how exact you should use it to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I'll check it again. My requirement for this part was quite simple and was addressed by a simple random string generator in beanshell though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to have the values for a given variable name in the same column.

Doing: `abd sds ase sdd ssd cvv` is very different from

```
abd 
sds 
ase 
sdd 
ssd 
cvv
```

The first has 6 variables with one value each; the second has one variable with 6 values.

Comment: Yes, thanks I am aware of that, I wanted them to be assigned to the same variable (but a new value each time a reference is made)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

CSV Dataset does not seem to be a suitable too for this purpose.

I ended up creating some simple beanshell scripts that create a random 1, 2, or 3 letter word as needed, and also another one that reads a random words from a large set. This way, each time they are called they give a random value. They are called like this:

```
${__BeanShell(getRandomStr(3))}
```

or

```
${__BeanShell(getRandomWord())
```