# How Can I Read The Next Row From A CSV Data Set Config In JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am in the process of creating a test place in JMeter which visits a random amount of pages (from 2 - 10), whose URLs are to be fetched from a CSV Data Set. I have created the CSV Data Set and the samplers which are working fine, except that only one row is read from the Data Set per thread, which is not as a I need - I want a new row to be read after the sampler has completed (or before, I'm not fussed).

I saw that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317943/jmeter-csv-dataset-config-how-to-move-through-variables-in-the-same-thread) is very similar and the solution was to use the [Raw Data Source](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RawDataSource) Pre-Processor, which does work but requires arduous alterations to the file in question (adding chunk sizes before each line), which is a bit of a pain when the file is about 500 lines long.

Is there a way I can set the CSV Data Set to advance to the next row on reading, or use some post or pre processor, such as beanshell, in order to do this? I have seen people state that [CSVRead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) can do this, but that states that access is per-thread, which would be no good for me.

As a side note - ultimately all I want to do is access a random line in the file which gets passed to a HTTP sampler, if there is an easier or better way to do this I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You can possibly use for this beanshell (= java) code executed from [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) / [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) / [BeanShell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor).

The following code will read all the lines from your file and then select single random:

```java
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

String [] params = Parameters.split(",");
String csvTest = params[0];
String csvDir = params[0];

ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();     

try {
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + csvDir + File.separator + csvTest);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new Exception ("ERROR: file " + csvTest + " not found in " + csvDir + " directory.");
    }

    BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;

    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
        strList.add(line);
    }

    bufRdr.close();            

    Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
    vars.put("csvUrl",strList.get(rnd.nextInt(strList.size())));
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    IsSuccess = false; 
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
    System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
```

Then you can access extracted URL via variable (${csvUrl} in this example).

I doubt only that reading full file on each iteration (if you have to execute this in loop) is good solution from performance point of view.