# How to get random data from CSV file in JMeter

Tags: java, csv, random, jmeter, beanshell

We are planning to pick Random data from CSV file in Jmeter. But we know there is no option in CSV Data Config. So we are planning to implement the Bean-shell Pre processor.

Any other idea to get Random data from Csv Files?

[image: For Example]

Comment: By "random" you mean the ability to get values in C5, then B2 and then D7?

Comment: it is much better (and you will have much better performance from jmeter) if you will not do any manipulations to the CSV file (or any other resource for that matter). jmeter requires a lot of resources from your machine just to generate load, and calculate statistics. adding additional CPU/Ram/IO for other tasks can hurt the load test itself.

Comment: @itaymendel Your answer is not related to the question. The question is how to generate the random number from the CSV file. Not to related with generate of loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the fastest and the easiest solution would be using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which provides RANDOM read mode, something like:

```
http://localhost:9191/sts/READ?READ_MODE=RANDOM&KEEP=TRUE&FILENAME=foo.csv
```

HTTP Simple Table Server can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager HTTP Simple Table Server]

Comment: Update: there is now a dedicated [plugin for reading random values out of a CSV file](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md), also installable from the plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomise your CSV file before reading it.

Randomise the order of entries in your CSV file before the test - and then read prepared data sequentially, in a way you like (via CSV Data Set e.g.).
You can do the preparation using e.g. Perl script or even via [Excel Random Sorting](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip093.shtml).

Also, you can try `BeanShell Sampler` something like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192319/how-can-i-read-the-next-row-from-a-csv-data-set-config-in-jmeter/10196360#10196360).

Answer (score 0):

You can use blazemeter plugin for picking random data from csv file. Here is link to how you can implement
[Random CSV Data Set Config plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter)

This is a very simple implementation, Hope this helps.