# Jmeter select random value from CSV data

Tags: rest, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a CSV file contains of `userId` If I tried to use CSV Data Set Config its reading from top to bottom until the last value. But example I want to simulate random `userId` from the list of CSV file how can I simulate this? I don't want to fix my `userId`  I want random `userId` from CSV file. I tried to avoid to use user defined variables because I have more than 50k `user_id` and based from my machine specs it's unable to handle the load that's why I'm planning to migrate to CSV file.

Current Behavior if I used `${userId}` on my Jmeter:

> 123
> 321
> 55
> 11
> 22
> 33
> 44
> 55
> 66
> 77
> 88
> 99
> 39
> 111

Here's my CSV File:

[image]

Jmeter File

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993994/how-to-get-random-data-from-csv-file-in-jmeter?rq=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) there is [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) which provides "Random mode"

[image]

Alternative options are:

1. [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which provides RANDOM mode of reading
2. You can shuffle the file beforehand somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/)