# mix different rows of data as input in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I've channel id values 1 through 600 but their values are long string. 
I've one CSV file with those 600 string values from row 1 to 600.
For every thread, i need to send different combination of channel ids.
Example:
thread1 should use channel id1, channel id2, channel id3 
thread2 should use channel id4, channel id5, channel id1, channel id2
similarly different combinations of row values have to passed as input.
I can create a new CSV with different combinations but it is a tedious manual process.
Can someone suggest how i can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter CSV Dataset Config: how to move through variables in the same thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317943/jmeter-csv-dataset-config-how-to-move-through-variables-in-the-same-thread)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, That did not address the issue as the channelid values i've to use are a) very specific string values (that cannot be randomized) and b) should be able to send values of multiple rows (not just single row alone for every thread)